# I'm Indian, opting for visa on arrival at Phuket. Do I need to carry cash?

Tags: indian-citizens, money, thailand, visas-on-arrival

Indian citizen, Indian passport, travelling from India to Phuket airport.

1. Somebody told me that you can't pay the visa on arrival fee using cards. Is this accurate?
2. Is there an ATM before the visa counter where I can withdraw THB currency (say using a forex card)?

Comment: This was many years ago and my memory is hazy, but I think they take THB only. I don't remember seeing ATMs anywhere. I would advise carrying THB. I think there used to be an express lane with additional fee. If the queue is considerably shorter then it might be worth paying, so carrying some extra cash might be worth it.

Comment: It was 2017, when I visited. They was only taking cash. I converted enough money beforehand. Didn't notice the ATMs. Adding as comment, as it might be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

See this account of my visa on arrival in Phuket:
https://insertindian.wordpress.com/2019/06/20/thailand-e-visa-on-arrival-update/

Basically, I applied for the VoA and paid online before departure. I still had to go to a separate visa counter at Phuket airport upon arrival to get a passport stamp, but they didn't ask for money.